# Assign a math operator to a variable without IF - System.MissingMemberException

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to send operation sign via string variable (`cal_Operation`) but I get an error.

NOTES:

- label1 will hold the result
- text1 hold one of the two numbers that will make calculation on them
- text2 hold the second number of the two numbers that will make
  calculation on them
- cal_Operation string hold the operation sign (- or + or / or - )

The code is:

```
Dim cal_Operation As String
Public newops = New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double))() From {
        {"+", Function(x, y) x + y},
        {"-", Function(x, y) x - y},
        {"*", Function(x, y) x * y},
        {"/", Function(x, y) x / y}
```

And I have radio buttons to assign the operation to the string variable
In the button I insert this code

```
RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
   cal_Operation = "+" 
   Dim op1 = newops(cal_Operation)
   Label1.Text = CStr(op1(CDbl(TextBox1.Text), CDbl(TextBox2.Text)))
End Sub
```

but i get this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll Additional information: No
>   default member found for type 'Func(Of Double,Double,Double)'.

what is the reason and the solution?

Comment: Can you show how you're populating `cal_Operation`? Does it work if you hard code its value to one of the operators in the dictionary?

Comment: i have radio buttons and this inside them


    Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged


        cal_Operation = "+"


    End Sub

Comment: +1 for a good example of the dangers of relying on type inference (and Option Strict Off).  Type inference only works at the procedure level, not the class as you have tried.  Since `newops` will be typed as an Object so will `op1` in `RadioButton1_CheckedChanged` and hence late-binding error message you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the declaration of the `newops` dictionary and be explicit on its type

```
Public newops as Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double)) = 
       New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double))() From {
{"+", Function(x, y) x + y},
{"-", Function(x, y) x - y},
{"*", Function(x, y) x * y},
{"/", Function(x, y) x / y}}
```